# Cannot escape double quotation in JAVA

Tags: java, escaping, character

I'm struggling to escape the double quotation marks when I try to convert my Map to String

```
//iterate through map and append to array
    StringBuilder mapAsString = new StringBuilder("{");
    for (String key : billingDetails.keySet()) {
        mapAsString.append(key + ":" + billingDetails.get(key) + ", ");
    }
    mapAsString.delete(mapAsString.length()-2, mapAsString.length()).append("}");
    String bdResult = mapAsString.toString();
```

Current output

```
"position": [
"{2018:Element3, 2012:Element2, 2010:Element1}"
```

Expected output

```
"position": [
"{"2018":"Element3", "2012":"Element2", "2010":"Element1"}"
```

Following method appends the contents of the Map to String however I can't seem to figure out how to escape the quotation marks so that the expected output is correct

```
 mapAsString.append(key + ":" + billingDetails.get(key) + ", ");
```

Escaping characters in java has always been somewhat of a difficulty for me and I would appreciate it if someone with a wider knowledge would help me out

Cheers and thanks

Comment: You should look into using a JSON library; don't build JSON this way by hand.

Comment: If you are trying to convert into a JSON, it's better to use a JSON library like GSON, Jackson, or even one of the simple ones, rather than try to do what has been done many times before.

Comment: Can you share a bit more context on what your input data is and how you're parsing that? Are you sure that the elements are separate entries in the map? Looking at the output, the map might have only 1 entry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using GSON already however I need to build a nested json object and it looks like my option is to convert the Map into an array and append the values. That's why I'm trying this method.

Comment: @BertJanSchrijver Hi Bert, 

All elements are separate entries in the map. What I'm trying to do is build a neste JSON object like such

[{"2010" : "Element1", "2012":"Element2"},

{"2018":"Element3", "2020":"Element4"} ]

Comment: If you are using `Gson` you should really just give it the full map as an element, it will convert it properly. If you pass it a string, it will automatically escape all the quotes in that string. In fact, your requested output is an illegal JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes with an backslash

```
mapAsString.append("\"" + key + "\":\"" + billingDetails.get(key) + "\", ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up however now the output is

`code`"position": [
    "\"2018\":\"Element3\", \"2012\":\"Element2\", \"2010\":\"Element1\""
  ],

Comment: If I'm execute the following code I get the result you want: https://codebunk.com/b/9981100101953/ . How do you set the value inside the array, maybe you have an interceptor/converter that converts the quotes?